TikZ -- Best strategy to choose points for the Hobby algorithm
I am trying to draw some nice curves (on the plane) like the ones below:

using the Hobby algorithm library for TikZ by Andrew Stacey, because it seems to produce the most balanced curves. But I am having a hard time choosing the points to represent the curve well, as you can see on the code below:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz[closed hobby] \draw plot coordinates {
        (0,0) (2.5,2.5) (5.4,0) (4.5,-1) (3.75,0) (4.5,1) (6.2,0) (8, -0.9) (8.9,0) (8,0.8) (7.1,0) (2.5,-2)
        (10:2cm)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

where all the points choosen are on the top curve, and which produces:

What would be the best strategy to choose the points? I have tried following the density of the curve on the plane, increasing it along with the curvature, equally spacing it along the curve, madling increasing the number of points ... but none of these seem to hit a good spot.

The problem was on the termination of the path, just do it closed and do not repeate the last coordinate. Stacey can certainly tell you about the best strategies to choose the points, but you can do a pretty close graphic with these points you have:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) to 
           [closed, curve through={(2.5,2.5) (5.4,0) (4.5,-1) (3.75,0) (4.5,1) (6.2,0) (8, -0.9) (8.9,0) (8,0.8) (7.1,0) }] 
           (2.5,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

will get you:

My answer shows you how todo it -- with your own data points -- it does not address the issue of what is the best strategy to choose a set of point. The Hobby algorithm is known to be extremely resilient, so picking up just a few point should be enough to get a result very close to the uinitial one.
I have tried just that, for your second curve. Followed a strategy of minimizing the set of points to be used. I picked up a ruler and draw a horizontal line in the middle of curve and picked up all 8 points where it crosses that line, plus 4 points off that line -- one on the top and three at the bottom.
With these set of points:
(1,0) (-2,0) (0,-2) (3,0) (6,2) (7,0) (6,-2) (4,0) (6,0) (5,-1) (2,0) (-1,0

you get again a pretty close curve to the one you have:

Observe that the direction of traversing the path here is contrary to the direction of the arrow.
